# openVPN, how to secure the web login?

Tags: openvpn

In installed the openvpn one click app installer thing with linode, and it works great.  I even purchased an SSL cert and added it via the UI so that users would not have to accept a dodgy web cert.

Its a simple VPN just to give a fixed IP (the ip of the server its on) to a user.

Users can login and download the client from the site and start using it, the config is magically built in.

The problem is security. there is nothing to stop brute force attacks on the login page.

I am guessing its possible for VPN users to be required to have a cert as well as the login, but I have no idea how to do this. Googling openvpn and certificate only gives articles on how to add the web cert, which is not relevant in this case.  Once we find a way to use certs, the next problem is how to tell the users how to change their configs to use the cert, or how to configure openVPN to matically download the new configs?

Presumably also its worth moving the web UI from 443 to another port, but again I can't find any articles or guides on how to do this.  Can it be done by wen config, config file, or does it require finding out how it started hand hacking the startup scripts?

I can SSH to the debian box which openVPN "appliance" was installed on, but I have no idea how linode have set it up, where its installed, how they start it etc.  They don't share the 1 click app scripts unfortunately.

Interestingly, in the network settings UI panel, there is a section for adin, which says it should be on port 943. But since I uploaded the web certs, its jumped to 443, and there seems no way to change?

I guess I could try to disable the admin on the external IP, only have it on localhost, then use a ssh tunnel to admin it. However, the users account could still get brute forced.

I need the sever to be accessible from anywhere, so cant lock down the ips to only specific ones.

I am surprised there are no how to articles for this kind of thing though.

Bazarly, under user permissions web admin dialog, there is an option to set  "Require user permissions record for VPN access" to Yes. Default is No.   But this cant be right - its implying anyone can use the vpn without a user login, which is not the case?

I see there is an option to enable goolge authenticator 2fa. Is this a good idea?  would this solve the brute force hack issue or not?  If so, why is this, or simlar anti-hack mechanism, not default or at least advised strongly somewhere?  Can multiple users share the same account with 2FA enabled?  Not at teh same time obviously, but at different times, with the same account but different authenticator devices?

Comment: Are you trying to solve the security of the VPN or logging in to the web server?

Comment: When you install openvpn, you get a web interface. users have to login to this interface to download the client and its corresponding config.  Admins login to create new clients, and also to get the client and configs.  This web interface would be easy to brute force attack. I am trying to find a way to help prevent this (and any other recommended security fixes). I can use the command line, but am not a linux or networking guru.

Comment: Modify the code to record login failures and block an IP when there are to many. If that's not practical, use fail2ban to monitor the logs to do something similar. (If you want user certificates for the web login, the term to google is "client side certificates", but this does not sound practical for your usage case. Running on port 443 vs something else is not a security risk.

Comment: Hi Davidgo, fail2ban only works at the SSH level, I dont think it works for failed web logins.

Comment: That is not correct.  Fail2Ban monitors logfiles and acts on what it finds as they are being written.  I know this to an absolute certainly as I have my systems configured to use fail2ban in this way.

Comment: sounds great. Could you point me to how to setup fail2ban to monitor openvpn login log files, and how to get it to disable the offending login, then how to re-enable it later?

Comment: Have you tried Googling? https://peaksandprotocols.com/mitigating-an-openvpn-brute-force-attack-with-fail2ban-on-edgerouter/

Comment: I have seen numerous posts with this config, but they are all on UDP port 1194 and deal with TLS errors. I specifically want to protect the web login on port TCP 443, not the client applications connection on UDP 1194. If they can brute force login to the website, they will be able to download a VALID login on 1194, so this protection is of no value.

Comment: so follow the logic and make your own rules to monitor the appropriate apache log file.